# Radio button should be checked after switching to next page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, radio-button

Radio button gets unchecked after I switch to next page using pagination. After switching when I come back to previous pages it gets unchecked. I want that it should hold the value or it should be checked.

I am new to Codeigniter.

Comment: you have a lot of option regarding this. You can use jquery or while loading the page back you should check that data exist or not and depend on that you should do the coding.

Answer (score 0):

After submitting form you can put the value of checkbox in session and after coming back to previous page you can retrieve it from session and make it checked.

> Set Radio button value in session

```
$this->session->set_userdata('name',value);
```

> Retrieve value from session and make checkbox checked.

```
<?php
$checked_value = $this->session->userdata('name');
?>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?= ($checked_value == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?> />
```

Implement this in your code.

Comment: In this solution what does **name** and **value** stands for.?

Comment: name means `session name` and value means `session value`.

Comment: hey..I am not getting it perfectly..actually i am fetching 10 quiz question each having four different options from database..displaying those data using pagination one at a time with 4 options..now when i switch after answering first question and go back to previous i found radio button gets unchecked..i want it should be checked